# System.IO.FileNotFoundException with no description

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I'm currently updating a Unity project from 2018.4.36f1 to 2020.3.24f1 to remove the SteamVR system an use the XR Interaction toolkit.
Most of the changes and errors have been solved but the following persists:

```
(0,0): error System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
```

No description is given and clicking on it does not lead anywhere.
What could I do?
EDIT: added image with errors and warnings: as you can see there were some codegen errors (autoreferencing) that was solved and left these warnings.
[image: erros and Warnings]

Comment: Try to searh the error in Editor.log